# Mockito/PowerMockito - Mock a method that receives Lambda expression as a parameter

Tags: mockito, powermockito

I want to mock the following method. But I don't find any `Mockito.Matchers` for the second parameter which uses `Java.util.Function`.

```
public List<String> convertStringtoInt(List<Integer> intList,Function<Integer, String> intToStringExpression) {
        return intList.stream()
                .map(intToStringExpression)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
Mockito.when(convertStringtoInt(Matchers.anyList(),Matchers.anyFunction()).thenReturn(myMockedList)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to mock the Function argument then either of the following would work:

```
Mockito.when(convertStringtoInt(Matchers.anyList(), Mockito.any(Function.class))).thenReturn(myMockedList);

Mockito.when(convertStringtoInt(Matchers.anyList(), Mockito.<Function>anyObject())).thenReturn(myMockedList);
```

Given a class, `Foo`, which contains the method: `public List<String> convertStringtoInt(List<Integer> intList,Function<Integer, String> intToStringExpression)` the following test case passes:

```
@Test
public void test_withMatcher() {
    Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);

    List<String> myMockedList = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c");

    Mockito.when(foo.convertStringtoInt(Matchers.anyList(), Mockito.<Function>anyObject())).thenReturn(myMockedList);

    List<String> actual = foo.convertStringtoInt(Lists.newArrayList(1), new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer integer) {
            return null;
        }
    });

    assertEquals(myMockedList, actual);
}
```

Note: if you actually want to invoke and control the behaviour of the Function parameter then I think you'd need to look at [thenAnswer()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs).

Comment: @Glictch. This works perfectly. Brilliant !!! `Mockito.when(convertStringtoInt(Matchers.anyList(), Mockito.<Function>anyObject())).thenReturn(myMockedList);`

Comment: What if I want to test a specific input lambda?